# How do I write a script to list those layers with broken data sources?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

In my SHP to GDB toolbox, I create a list of layers in MXD, then I check for those not broken I move them. Despite using ListBrokenDataSources I have errors like this:

> Runtime error : [Error 3] Impossible
>   trovare il percorso specificato:
>   u'J:\20120208_Backup_disco_E\Archivio\ATLArete\Shape Atlarete
>   1-1-2008\miste.shp'

**Translate:**

> Runtime error : [Error 3] Unable to
>   find the specified path:
>   u'J:\20120208_Backup_disco_E\Archivio\ATLArete\Shape Atlarete
>   1-1-2008\miste.shp'

Here is my code:

```
# Create a list of SHP in mxd 
    list = []
    df_list = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd)

    for df in df_list: 
        for fc in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd, "", df):
            if (fc.supports("DATASOURCE")) and (fc.dataSource.endswith(".shp")):
                        list.append(fc)
    print("List created")

    # Check for borken datasource
    for fc in list:
        if arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(fc):
            list.remove(fc)
    print ("Broken data removed from list")

    # Move fc to gdb
    add_list = []
    for fc in list:
        fc_date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(fc.dataSource)))
        try:
            dsc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
            out_temp = '_' + fc_date + '_' + fc.name + '_' + fc_prj
            out_name = arcpy.ValidateTableName(out_temp)
            print ('Created ' + out_name + ' to ' + gdb_full_path)
        except:
            out_temp = '_' + fc_date + '_' + fc.name + '_' + 'UNKNOWN'
            out_name = arcpy.ValidateTableName(out_temp)
            print ('Created ' + out_name + ' to ' + gdb_full_path)
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, fd_path, out_name)
        replace_name = fd_path + '\\' + out_name
        fc.replaceDataSource (gdb_full_path, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", out_name)
        print ('Replaced data source ' + out_name + ' in ' + gdb_full_path)


    # Create a new MXD
    new_mxd = os.path.splitext(gdb_full_path)[0] + '\\' + 'MXD' + '\\' +  time.strftime("%Y%m%d", mxd_date )+ '_' + (mxd_name)
    mxd.saveACopy(new_mxd)
    print ('Created new MXD ' + new_mxd + ' in ' + ws)
```

Comment: @Mapperz: I don't get what you edited, can you be more clear?